# Set up aws s3 for image uploads with spree

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, spree

I am trying to use aws s3 in my spree rails app.

Here's how I am trying to set it up.

I have `gem 'aws-sdk', '< 2.0'` in my `Gemfile`.

Below is my `spree.rb` under initializer.

```
 Spree.config do |config|
 end

Spree.user_class = "Spree::User"
 attachment_config = {
 s3_credentials: {
 access_key_id:     ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'],
 secret_access_key: ENV['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'],
 bucket:            ENV['S3_BUCKET_NAME']
},
storage:        :s3,
s3_headers:     { "Cache-Control" => "max-age=31557600" },
s3_protocol:    "https",
bucket:         ENV['S3_BUCKET_NAME'],
url:            ":s3_domain_url",

styles: {
  mini:     "48x48>",
  small:    "100x100>",
  product:  "240x240>",
  large:    "600x600>"
},

path:           "/:class/:id/:style/:basename.:extension",
default_url:    "/:class/:id/:style/:basename.:extension",
default_style:  "product"
}

attachment_config.each do |key, value|
  Spree::Image.attachment_definitions[:attachment][key.to_sym] = value
end
```

When I am running this, I am getting

> ArgumentError in Spree::Home#index

```
missing required :bucket option
```

I am not sure what's missing, Can someone point out ?

Answer (score 0):

Double check if you are setting `S3_BUCKET_NAME` in your environment.

Then your spree.rb should look like this

```
Spree.config do |config|
end
Spree.user_class = "Spree::User"
attachment_config = {
    s3_credentials: {
        access_key_id: ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'],
        secret_access_key: ENV['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'],
        bucket: ENV['S3_BUCKET_NAME']
    },
    storage:        :s3,
    s3_headers:     { "Cache-Control" => "max-age=31557600" },
    s3_protocol:    "https",
    styles: {
        mini:     "48x48>",
        small:    "100x100>",
        product:  "240x240>",
        large:    "600x600>"
    },
    path:           "/:class/:id/:style/:basename.:extension",
    default_url:    "/:class/:id/:style/:basename.:extension",
    default_style:  "product"
}
attachment_config.each do |key, value|
    Spree::Image.attachment_definitions[:attachment][key.to_sym] = value
end
```